# Stacking a UIImagePickerController inside a navigation controller?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uiimagepickercontroller

My app basically has two view controllers, starting in a navigation controller:

1) MainViewController, which asks user to pick Camera or Album and then presents UIImagePicker

2) PhotoViewController, which receives photo.

However, in the second VC, when the user hits "Back", I would prefer to immediately return to either the Camera or Album they selected, rather than MainVC and then reloading the picker.

Should I separate an entirely new ViewController dedicated to the ImagePicker rather than presenting it within MainViewController? Using `pushViewController:` doesn't work as `'Pushing a navigation controller is not supported'` perhaps meaning that imagePickers are nav controllers too.

MainViewController currently displays it like this:

```
[self.navigationController presentViewController:self.imagePicker animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Any suggestions appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution could be inside your MainVC have 2 bool values calledCamera, calledLibrary
when you create your new VC you set the one you choose your pic from to YES. So when you come back...

```
- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
       [super viewWillAppear:animated];

       if (calledCamera){

        //call cameraPicker to load before de MainVc shows
        }

       if (calledLibrary){

      //call the LibraryPicker before...
        }
  }
```